# > /dev/null 2>&1 still has output in stdout

Tags: shell

I try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$(< temp.temp) > /dev/null 2>&1

echo $var
```

I expected no outputs whether temp.temp exists or not.
But when I tried these command, it still has outputs. Could you help on this? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you expect no outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
{ var=$(<temp.temp); } 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

`var=$(< temp.temp) > /dev/null 2>&1`

should be

`var=$(>/dev/null 2>&1 < temp.temp)`

You assign a variable a value and redirect the output of that assignment, which makes no sense.

What you need is to *first* redirect `stdout` and `stderr`, then try to read from the file, because it gets interpreted from left to right, meaning that when you try to read `temp.temp`, `stdout` and `stderr` **hasn't** been redirected, thus you see a message about file not found or the contents of the file.